# How to manage a monorepo with the option to release minor versions for packages after newer major versions have been released

Tags: flutter-dependencies, monorepo

Sometimes it is necessary to release a new version of a package with a lower major version number than the most recently released major version.
For example, after we released (v2.0.0) and (v3.0.0), we need to release (v2.0.1) that contain specific fixes for (v2.0.0). The customer do not want to get othen than those changes.
In case that we have a repository for each of the packages, we manage a branch for each major version.
In case that we manage in a monorepo, what is the best practices?
We use flutter/dart.

I checked Melos, and did not find the use case.